# Does MariaDB 10.1+ have array/collection types for variables?

Tags: mariadb

Does MariaDB have anything like arrays for variables? (Not for storage into a table. Instead I was hoping to use them to hold values to be used individually in queries.)

For example:

`SELECT ... WHERE x = myVAR[1]`;

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean?

```
SELECT ... FROM tbl WHERE x IN (1,4,767,443)

SELECT ... FORM tbl .. -- and get any "rows"; this is like an array.

SET @variable := 123;  -- not an array, but a scalar, for use thus:
SELECT ... WHERE x = @variable;
```

Comment: Sorry for not posting an example. I was thinking of this: `SELECT ... WHERE x = myVAR[1]`

Comment: Nothing like that.